# fetching data from MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I have a MongoDB collection with number of items. Multiple items have a same key vlue(*srkey*), but value of their *timestamp* is different. I want to to fetch all items by *srkey* with greatest *timestamp*. How to accomplish this with **php MongoDB.**

For example the my collection contains following items

- collection

  ```
  item1 : {srkey:a,timestamp:1358675171}
  item2 : {srkey:b,timestamp:1358675175}
  item3 : {srkey:a,timestamp:1358676849}
  item4 : {srkey:d,timestamp:1358675213}
  item5 : {srkey:b,timestamp:1358676111}
  ```

Output of fetch must be

```
    item3 : {srkey:a,timestamp:1358676849}
    item4 : {srkey:d,timestamp:1358675213}
    item5 : {srkey:b,timestamp:1358676111}
```

Item 1 and 3 have same srkey, so the result  contains only one of the them with greatest timestamp value.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you mean? I am failing to quite picture this from the description

Comment: `I have a MongoDB collection with no of items` - do you want to use find on empty collection?

Comment: i think you did't understood the question by yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new aggregation framework for this:

```
$db->col->aggregate(array(
    array('$sort' => array('$timestamp' => -1)),
    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$srkey', 
        'timestamp' => array('$first' => '$timestamp')))
));
```

It should be the first of that sorted group since you are sorting in a DESC manner.

Comment: @HarishAnchu What do you mean by server error? Can you post the actual error?

Comment: @HarishAnchu Turn on PHP error reporting, it should catch stuff like fatal errors and that

Comment: @HarishAnchu I wonder a sec, what version of the driver are you running? Can you just do a quick phpinfo() and see what the section under `mongo` says?

Comment: @HarishAnchu Bam there is your problem, the aggregate helper was added in 1.3, you can use the command to do this but I recommend you upgrade it only takes 5 mins

Comment: This works fine, thanks again. But it returns only fields specified  in the grouping array. I need all fields of the items.(There are more fields in the items of my collection. In my example I just specified two of them).

Comment: @HarishAnchu Yea this is stil a flaw with MongoDBs aggregation framework, in SQL of course it kinda knows this but in MongoDB you have specify the fields manually, so just copy the `timestamp` group field and do it however many times you need :)